# Display compiled Angular app inside React Native

Tags: react-native

The company I work for has ****many**** small angular applications they would like to make available in an phone app. Mostly because the users are usually in poor connection places so it would be nice if they only need to make the API calls and not load resources, and they also want to be able to make push notifications for new events.

So looking into this I'm trying to see if its possible to embed Angular (v13 as of now) applications inside of React Native. Where the react app will mostly act as a menu and notifications handler.

To be honest I haven't found much help online besides that I probably need to use a `<WebView>`. So i tried compiling a simple Angular app and placed it in `/assets/my-app/`
and then tried the following (with a few variations on how I wrote the URL).

```
<WebView source={{uri: '~/assets/my-app/index.html'}} style={{marginTop: 20}} />
```

But that did not work at all.

So, my questions are:

1. Can this be done?
2. Is this the right method?
3. How do I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: would be easy to wrap in capacitor.js

Comment: ^ Agree with @Indraraj26, see here for more: https://capacitorjs.com/blog/turn-your-angular-app-native